# What are some approaches to reducing controller complexity in angular (with ui-router)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular with ui-router. I have a very event driven form which corresponds to a controller which currently holds many `$scope` callback functions as such:

```
controller: function($scope, $localForage, $stateParams) {
   $scope.addMaterialRow = function(){
      ...
   };

   $scope.save = function() {
      ...
   };
   ...
}
```

What are some approaches I could take to reduce the complexity in the controller? It is getting quite big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that stands out from your example is to use the controllerAs syntax. This eliminates the need to bind directly to the `$scope`.

As well, define your controller separately from the ui-router state configuration.

```
// ui-router state config
controller: "YourController",
controllerAs: "vm"
```

Then in a file all on its own your controller looks like:

```
YourController.$inject = ['$localForage', '$stateParams']
function YourController($localForage, $stateParams) {
    this.$localForage = $localForage;
    this.$stateParams = $stateParams;
};

YourController.prototype.addMaterialRow = function() {...}

YourController.prototype.save = function() {...}

angular.module('yourModule').controller('YourController', YourController);
```

In your view, you will prefix the controller actions with `vm.` like `<a ng-click="vm.save()"></a>`

Answer (score 2):

It might help to see more functions from your controller.  Offhand, though, the obvious ones are:

1. Offload logic to a factory/service.  This is especially convenient if your form data needs to be shared or persisted across states.
2. Go the more Angular 2 / React route and componentize a lot of the view by using directives.  For example, turn your complex form into a directive which maintains the logic for all the events and validation on the form.  If your form is event-driven, then communicating with other components should be a simple task.

Then your main view controller is sort of the traffic cop for the different directives on the view.